# DependencyProperties Difference between SetValue, GetValue and static SetPropName()

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, accessor

There are two ways to access dependency properties. Is there any difference in behaviour/reaction, or are they similar in usage?

First method:

```
 public static DependencyProperty TestProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Test",
                                            typeof (bool),
                                            typeof (MyBaseClass),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(true));

public static bool GetTest(UIElement element)
{
    return (bool) element.GetValue(TestProperty);
}

public static void SetTest(UIElement element, bool value)
{
    element.SetValue(TestProperty, value);
}
```

Second method:

```
 public static DependencyProperty TestProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Test",
                                            typeof (bool),
                                            typeof (MyBaseClass),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(true));

public bool Test {
    get {
        return (bool) GetValue(TestProperty);
    }
    set {
        SetValue(TestProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This entirely depends on, if you can actually have an instance of the class you are implementing this. The instance ones are usually used on `CustomControls` & `UserControls`. The static ones are used on Helper/Extension-classes where no inheritance of a `UIElement` is possible

Comment: That sounds clear. Thanks for your fast response!

Comment: The latter property declaration shouldn't use RegisterAttached, but Register instead. Use RegisterAttached for the declaration of an attached property with static getter and setter methods, and Register for a regular dependency property with a CLR property wrapper. See the [Dependency Properties Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN for more information.

Comment: @Clemens: thanks for your answer. I updated the question and changed to Register at second method.